# Wildcards in CSS selectors to match name variations

Tags: html, css

I'm using jquery to append some HTML (radio input buttons) and increment the `name=""` of the inputs.

In the CSS I'd like to be able to add a * to the end of the name like so:

```
input[type="radio"][name="state*"] { //css }
```

Is this possible or can I give each attribute a secondary value, like `name2="groupidentifier"`?

I know I can use `form input[type="radio"] { //css }` but thought this could be an interesting alternative for future reference.

Comment: Question title says "Variables in HTML". Should it be "Wildcards in CSS selectors" or I'm totally lost?

Comment: It's new to me so the names aren't top of mind, but that sounds correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
input[type="radio"][name^="state"] {
  /* Styling here */
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="state1" />
<input type="radio" name="state1" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="state2" />
<input type="radio" name="state2" />
</form>
```

Comment: What does the `^` bit do? I can't seem to make sense of the linked explainer.

Comment: @denski `^=` means "begins with"

Comment: Both useful answers, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your are looking for is something more like this:

```
input[type="radio"][name*="state"] { //css }
```

The * needs to part of the =

Comment: Would this also work for any inputs with the name `name="state216543"`?

Comment: @denski `*=` means "contains", meaning you could name the element "123state321" and it will still select it.